# Can Ubuntu (bash) on Windows replace LAMP Stack software like WAMP or XAMPP on Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bash, apache-http-server, lamp

I find bash on Windows especially useful and - afaik - you can install most of the ubuntu software that exists out there and get little to no difference compared to working on a real ubuntu os.

Therefore I would think that one could install PHP, MariaDB/MySQL and Apache and configure it as a local development server. This would completely replace the demand for software packages like WAMP and XAMPP. Also I think it would be actually closer to an production server, which would be an advantage.

**So, can Ubuntu (bash) on Windows fully replace WAMP or XAMPP on Windows (for development purposes)?**

If so, are there any disadvantages or restrictions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not particularly into web development but Microsofts intention by creating Bash on Ubuntu on Windows/Windows Subsystem for Linux was specifically to ease the life of web developers so that they have a familiar set of tools also on Windows. However, they also state that it's only intended for development and not ment to be used for production.

So: yes. For development purposes it should suffice.

Sources:

- https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/ (also contains some notes on limitations)
- https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/07/22/fun-with-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/